# Arch audio driver alsa can't hear audio via headset setup by pavucontrol/pulseaudio

Tags: arch-linux, pulseaudio, alsa

I have problems with using my headphone to receive audio output in arch.
I installed these packages:
`alsa`
`pulseaudio`
`pulseaudio-alsa`
`pavucontrol`

I ran `pulseaudio --run and started pavucontrol`. In pavucontrol my headphone was recognized and it's set to port `Analog Output`. When I move the Silence bar I can hear the clicking sound.
However when I start a youtube video or join a hangouts meeting I can not hear anything.

This is my headset: https://www.google.de/aclk?sa=L&ai=DChcSEwjLy5LeprTkAhWO4XcKHdtKBUUYABAIGgJlZg&sig=AOD64_3pb165d3QI6n23Xo1ElC3nZYzvSw&ctype=5&q=&ved=0ahUKEwjeiozeprTkAhVEL1AKHTj3DYMQ9aACCGY&adurl=

It is connected by USB and bluetoothing from there to the headphone.

In alsamixer:

- Card = PulseAudio
- Chip = PulseAudio
- Sound Card selected in Menu is
  _default

**lsmod | grep "snd":**

```
snd_usb_audio         278528  2
snd_usbmidi_lib        40960  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_rawmidi            45056  1 snd_usbmidi_lib
snd_seq_device         16384  1 snd_rawmidi
media                  61440  5 videodev,snd_usb_audio,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     69632  1
snd_sof_intel_hda_common    73728  1 sof_pci_dev
snd_sof_intel_hda      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_byt      28672  1 sof_pci_dev
snd_sof_intel_ipc      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_sof               118784  4 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt,snd_sof_intel_ipc,sof_pci_dev
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     16384  1 sof_pci_dev
snd_soc_skl           118784  0
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_ext_core       36864  4 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_soc_skl_ipc        73728  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_sst_ipc        20480  1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
snd_soc_sst_dsp        40960  1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    28672  3 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,sof_pci_dev,snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_acpi           16384  3 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,sof_pci_dev,snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_core          286720  4 snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_codec_realtek   126976  1
snd_compress           28672  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_codec_generic    94208  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_intel          53248  8
snd_hda_codec         159744  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_hda_core          102400  10 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_hwdep              20480  2 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               135168  13 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_timer              40960  3 snd_pcm
ledtrig_audio          16384  3 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek,thinkpad_acpi
snd                   110592  31 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,thinkpad_acpi,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
soundcore              16384  1 snd
```

**ls -l /dev/snd/:**

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root       60 Sep  4 03:17 by-id
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root      100 Sep  4 03:17 by-path
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  5 Sep  4 01:07 controlC0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 11 Sep  4 01:07 controlC1
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 14 Sep  4 03:17 controlC2
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  4 Sep  4 01:07 hwC0D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 10 Sep  4 01:07 hwC1D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  3 Sep  4 03:23 pcmC0D0c
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  2 Sep  4 03:09 pcmC0D0p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  6 Sep  4 02:48 pcmC1D3p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  7 Sep  4 03:18 pcmC1D7p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  8 Sep  4 02:48 pcmC1D8p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  9 Sep  4 02:48 pcmC1D9p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 13 Sep  4 03:28 pcmC2D0c
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 12 Sep  4 03:28 pcmC2D0p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  1 Sep  4 01:07 seq
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 Sep  4 01:07 timer
```

Comment: Check `alsamixer` maybe headphone is muted there.

Comment: In `alsamixer`I only see one entry for master. Before I brought `pulseaudio` onto my machine I could see more entries also headphones.

Comment: press F6 in alsamixer to select hardware devices, rather than Pulseaudio virtual device. pulseaudio-alsa in Arch distros creates asound.conf file for this

Comment: so was downloading pulseaudio-alsa a rather useless move?

Comment: pulseaudio-alsa easier than creating a custom asound.conf to connect pulseaudio and alsa. other distributions i know of add this file anyway as part of main pulseaudio package